# Error in Uploading the .ipa file using Application loader - Phonegap build - IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, application-loader

I have completed the phonegap app and even launched it in Google play store. But the problem arises when uploading the app to Apple istore. 
I have obtained the .ipa file from the Adobe Phonegap build after uploading the itunes certificates required. But now when trying to upload the application through application loader i am getting this error.

> "The bundle is invalid. The icon file must be in .png format"

I have generated all icons through photoshop and are in valid png format.
[image: error]

Also I have provided all the icons with a valid .png file as shown below in my config.xml file.

[image: config.xml]

After trying for more than 1 week i am just not able to upload my Phonegap ios app to the apple istore. Also in the official documentation of the Phonegap Build there are instructions only till we get the .ipa file and nothing is mentioned about how to upload it to Apple Istore.

Even a small help from a experienced Phonegap ios developer who has already been through this process will be life saver.

PS - Please also mention if there is any other way to upload the .ipa file ( Through Xcode or something else ) and also comment below if you need more information regarding my code or my config.xml file.

Comment: Look at your icon list - it doesn't include a launch image with the -568h size modifier, as explained in the error message. You must stick to Apple's rules exactly. Exactly. Don't worry - I went through this when I was using PhoneGap Build. I now use Ionic and Cordova though.